# Как реализовать поиск с выдачей результата в Google таблицах?

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Есть два столбца, в одном записаны размеры, а втором их количество. Нужно реализовать поиск по ним,  в одну ячейку записываем, то что нужно найти, а в другой будет выдан результат. Например, ищем 3,40 результат должен выдавать если есть такой, а если нет такого размера, то сложить из несколько размеров (2+1,40 =3,40) или приближённый результат к этому значению, но есть ещё количество этих размеров
Как можно такое реализовать?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1a7e3SiwTqgpe9dm9vj8DdxG6A1YgBMNMbBgF4AXD4Ik/edit?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Нужен пример, сложно из описания словами понять, к сожалению. Можете создать гуглотаблицу, внести данные и отметить что хотели бы ожидать в ячейках?

Comment: *если нет такого размера, то сложить из несколько размеров* Без этого дополнения можно было бы обойтись формулой с ВПР (VLOOKUP). Но с ним - только программно. Так что Инструменты - Редактор скриптов ...

Comment: В ячейке результат поиска, хотел бы видеть данные ячейок з размерами типу искать 3,40 результат в ячейке «2+1,40» или «3,40» – если есть такой размер, «1+1+1,40» либо наближеной результат «2,14+1,20» = 3,34